# A silly error from a MySQl query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have the following query:

```
SELECT rate AS theRate, 
       currency AS curr 
  FROM _currency 
 WHERE country_code ='GBP'
```

And I get the error

> #1054 - Unknown column 'currency' in 'field list'.

"_currency" is the name of the table I am using and it's really bugging me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run this and post output: `describe _currency;`

Comment: can you add your _currency table with structure  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't about table name `_currency`. It is about column `currency`. You, apparently, don't have column with such name in that table.

Comment: @Way: No problem. Welcome to stackoverflow, by the way. When you find that an answer solves your problem, you should accept it (the little check mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error would appear to be in this section:

```
currency as curr
```

Check the name of that column.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table structure for the field 'currency'.